# Terminate the pod if the queue is empty

Tags: docker, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am creating

- A pod every two minutes using cron-job
- It has custom python image that reads the data from redis

The problem is, it keeps on creating pods every two minutes irrespective of others terminated or not, I am trying to terminate the pod, if I get a response like "Empty" from the pod, the operation that is running in the pod, gives the response like that, if it doesn't give response like this, I want to terminate within 10 sec.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like

```
kubectl wait --for=condition=complete job/jobname
```

and you can also set a timeout:

```
kubectl wait --for=condition=complete --timeout=10s job/jobname
```

Example python script that will be checking the redis

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import time
import rediswq

host="redis"
# Uncomment next two lines if you do not have Kube-DNS working.
# import os
# host = os.getenv("REDIS_SERVICE_HOST")

q = rediswq.RedisWQ(name="job2", host=host)
print("Worker with sessionID: " +  q.sessionID())
print("Initial queue state: empty=" + str(q.empty()))
while not q.empty():
  item = q.lease(lease_secs=10, block=True, timeout=2) 
  if item is not None:
    itemstr = item.decode("utf-8")
    print("Working on " + itemstr)
    time.sleep(10) # Put your actual work here instead of sleep.
    q.complete(item)
  else:
    print("Waiting for work")
print("Queue empty, exiting")
```

ref : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/fine-parallel-processing-work-queue/